# Ambari DB is damaged without Ambari DB backup

Tags: ambari, hdp

We have Ambari HDP cluster ( HDP version - 2.6.4 ) , with 420 workers linux machines ( when each worker include data node and node manager service )

Unfortunately Ambari DB is damaged , and we not have Ambari DB dump , so we cant recover Ambari DB  , so actually we not have Ambari and Ambari GUI

But HDFS disks on workers machines include HDFS data , and name node is still working with all data  as ( journal/hdfsha/current/ ) and ( namenode/current )

So HDFS works without Ambari

So regarding what I said until now - it is possible install new Ambari cluster and then add existing working HDFS to the cluster ?

Dose hortonworks / cloudera have procedure for this process ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An "Ambari cluster" is not something. You install Ambari agents and point the server at them.

If you wipe the database, then the agents may attempt to reconfigure your services, however, so you better take a backup of at least core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, yarn-site.xml, etc.

Comment: yes but about name-node meta data ? and HDFS data? ,

Comment: Ambari never touches any of that